# iloc[] by value columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use iloc with value in column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1' ,'1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3' ,'3','3'],
                'col2': ['A' ,'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I' ,'J','K']})
```

I want to select index 2 in each column value as data frame and the result will be like

```
col1 col2
   1    C
   2    F
   3    K
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('col1', as_index=False).nth(2)
```

Alternative with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df2 = df1[df1.groupby('col1').cumcount().eq(2)]
```

---

```
print (df2)
   col1 col2
2     1    C
5     2    F
10    3    K
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) with `as_index=False`:

```
df1.groupby('col1', as_index=False).nth(2)
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
2     1    C
5     2    F
10    3    K
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby('col1').agg(lambda ss:ss.iloc[2])

   col2
col1     
1       C
2       F
3       K
```